# Prevent/Remove Flicker from first page load

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, dom, nuxtjs

I've been working on a generated static website with NuxtJS in where the user can select whether or not to use dark mode or just go with the default CSS media query selector. The code for that is as follows:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <vertical-nav />
    <!-- wrapper for content; when state is updated, only then is the class added -->
    <div id="content-wrapper" :class="colorScheme !== null ? colorScheme : ''">
      <nuxt />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapMutations, mapState } from 'vuex';
import VerticalNav from '@/components/VerticalNav.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    VerticalNav,
  },
  // Vuex state that stores ui preference, by default null
  computed: mapState(['colorScheme']),
  mounted() {
    // Vuex mutation to set initial state
    this.getPreferredColorScheme();
  },
  methods: mapMutations(['getPreferredColorScheme']),
};
```

I've noticed that for a first page load, the webpage will flicker/flash [as shown in this screen recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/58kx9jl3rurjii5/StackOverFlowFlicker.mov?dl=0). Note that this is with the cache off.

Further investigation suggests that this is only happens for when it is the first time a user visits the site as subsequent visits/refreshes don't seem to trigger this behavior. I suspect it might be related to loading in of fonts and subsequently reflows as suggested by this [water](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7pyztkk0uz5a1g/waterfall.png?dl=0) [fall](https://www.dropbox.com/s/78pjl7josul7nps/overthinkingcode.net.har?dl=0). Please note that `display=swap` is not being used here and not desired. Additionally, from this profiler [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6z9276o13v10zzu/Profile-20200616T035605.json?dl=0) from Chrome, it seems that around the flicker, the browser decides to recalculate styles and layout all the nodes in the page (relevant time from 4.26 seconds to 4.32s).

What I am asking is the flash/flicker of invisible text caused by how I am adding the optional class? If the class binding is not the issue, what is the reason and is there anything I can do be about it?

EDIT: On further inspection, this behavior seems to only occur in Chrome and might be related to the self-hosted fonts I have. Firefox and Safari don't have this repaint behavior.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm experiencing exactly the same issue. Waterfall looks fine, it's just the initial first page load that's flickering.

Comment: Sorry, I had to dig through my commit history. Sadly, older me didn’t think to document exactly what he did and I can’t remember exactly. Best I can tell from my current site, looking at the waterfall, it seems that I was asking for the fonts twice and that seems to trigger a relayout. 

On my current version , the content flicker is gone and I don’t see the redownload of fonts anymore.

Comment: I managed to figure it out, my issue was that I had `font-display: swap` on my fonts.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a lot of things, it would be more helpful if you opened the inspector to show if anything failed to load.

With that said, the flicker isn't being caused by page load, it's being caused by your "Night mode" toggle, which is being toggled after page load.

If you want the page to load in "Night mode" then maybe consider loading it that way, rather than triggering it on load.

Comment: I’ve attached the waterfall diagram and believed nothing is failing to load. Also, I believe that the toggle itself, besides animating is not directly related to the rerender of the entire page.

Comment: At any rate, I am looking if there is a smoother experience with having the toggle. Removing the toggle is not an option.